# Axisymmetric cylindrical Laplace's equation with a boundary condition at infinity

Tags: differential-equations

I'm trying to solve Laplace's equation in cylindrical coordinates. The solution is axisymmetric and also symmetric with respect to the $r=0$ plane. Hence I only care about solving in one quadrant. The boundary conditions are:

- $u=0$ at infinity
- $u=a$ when $z=0$ and $r<R$

Below is my setup, which isn't evaluating. I've poured over Laplace and `DSolve` documentation but can't seem to find a good answer to two questions:

- Can I solve this problem analytically? I.e. can I get Mathematica to return an analytical solution with this setup?
- If I can't solve this analytically, must I setup a finite domain? I know I can solve this problem numerically by making a domain much larger than $a$ in all directions, meshing the domain, and using `NDSolve`, but I'd prefer to keep the domain infinite.

```
Eqn = Laplacian[u[r, \[Phi], z], {r, \[Phi], z}, "Cylindrical"] == 0;
BC1 = u[\[Infinity], \[Phi], z] == 0;
BC2 = u[r, \[Phi], \[Infinity]] == 0;
BC3 = ConditionalExpression[u[r, \[Phi], 0] == a, r < R];
DSolve[{Eqn, BC1, BC2}, u[r, \[Phi], z], {{r, 0, \[Infinity]}, {\[Phi], 0, 2 \[Pi]}, {z, 0, \[Infinity]}}]

(* Returns input *)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mathematica cannot DSolve a general linear PDE with nonconstant coefficients.

The Laplace equation for cylindrical coordinates separates into products of three functions of the variables.

$$\frac{1}{r} \  (r \ u'(r))' * v(\phi) * w(z)) + \frac{1}{r^2} \  u(r)* v''(\phi)* w(z) +  u(r) * v(\phi) * w''(z)==0$$

For rotational symmetry it follows $v(\phi)=1$ and there are two equations to solve by division with u*w

$$ \frac{1}{r u} (r u'(r))' = \text{const}  , \  \frac{w''}{w} =-\text{const}$$

The two boundary conditions are

$$ u(1)=1, w(0)=1 $$

It follows that $w(z) = e^{-|z|}$ by symmetry and $u(r)$ is a combination of Bessel functions $ J[0, k r] , \  Y[0, k r]$.

Comment: Thank you Roland! This approach makes sense, but I'm curious how you came up with those boundary conditions. I want the full function to have boundary conditions $U(r,\phi,0) = a$ when $r < R$ and $U(\infty,\phi,z) = U(r,\phi,\infty) = 0$. I also want the solution for $0\leq r< \infty$.

Comment: The boundary condition for $u(r=1)=1$ fits of course to u(r<1)=1 and with w(0)=1 for a constant solution in the unit disk at $z=0$.

Comment: I've never worked with Bessel functions in Mathematica - could you demonstrate how to combine the Bessel functions and plot the radial solution for your unit disk above? Would be much appreciated!

Comment: Any sum or integral over $k$ of  $ e^{-k z} BesselJ[0  k r]$ solves the Laplace equation. The boundary condition at $z=0. r=a, r=\infty$ is not the problem.   The problem is that for $r<a$ and small $z$ th solutions is nearly constant. Therefore, this problem is usuallymuch mor easily  solved in cylindrical oblate ellipsoidal coordinates, for which the disk of constant temperature is a natural singular boundary.  This is a common  textbook problem for an electrically charged disk.

Answer (score 1):

Oblate spheroidal coordinates are

```
 CoordinateTransformData[ "OblateSpheroidal" -> "Cartesian","Mapping"][
   {u, v,\[Phi]}]

   \[FormalA] Cos[\[Phi]] Cosh[u] Sin[v], 
    \[FormalA] Cosh[u] Sin[v] Sin[\[Phi]], 
      \[FormalA] Cos[v] Sinh[u]}


   Show[{ ParametricPlot[ Evaluate@
        Table[{Cosh[u] Sin[\[Phi]] , Cos[\[Phi]] Sinh[u]}, 
                 {\[Phi], 0, 2 \[Pi], \[Pi]/12}], {u, -1, 1}], 
 ParametricPlot[ Evaluate@
           Table[{Cosh[u] Sin[\[Phi]] , Cos[\[Phi]] Sinh[u]}, 
            {u, 0.01, 2,  2/12}], {\[Phi], 0, 2 \[Pi]}]}]
```

[image: oblate spheroidal]

For a function as a product in $u,v$ independent of $\phi$

```
   ((Laplacian[f[u] g[v], {u, v, \[Phi]}, "OblateSpheroidal" ] // 
  FullSimplify // PowerExpand // Numerator)/(f[u] g[v]) // Expand )==0
```

$$\frac{2 f''(u)}{f(u)}+\frac{2 \tanh (u) f'(u)}{f(u)}+\frac{2 g''(v)}{g(v)}+\frac{2 \cot (v) g'(v)}{g(v)} = 0$$

$$\text{DSolve}\left[\left\{2 \frac{\partial ^2f(u,v)}{\partial u\, \partial u}+2 \tanh (u) \frac{\partial f(u,v)}{\partial u}=c_1 f(u,v),2 \frac{\partial ^2g(u,v)}{\partial v\, \partial v}+2 \cot (v) \frac{\partial g(u,v)}{\partial v}=-c_1 g(u,v)\right\},\{f(u,v),g(u,v)\},\{u,v\}\right]$$

The general solution is

$$\left\{f(u,v)\to \sqrt[4]{-1} \sqrt{\text{sech}(u)} \left(c_2(v) P_{-\frac{1}{2}}^{\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{2 c_1+1}}(\tanh (u))+c_3(v) Q_{-\frac{1}{2}}^{\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{2 c_1+1}}(\tanh (u))\right),g(u,v)\to c_4(u) P_{\frac{1}{2} \left(\sqrt{2 c_1+1}-1\right)}(\cos (v))+c_5(u) Q_{\frac{1}{2} \left(\sqrt{2 c_1+1}-1\right)}(\cos (v))\right\}$$

There are 4 constants in order to fit boundary condtions and the separation constant c(1).